# Calling a JS function if cookie matched

Tags: javascript, cookies

I can't figure out what is wrong.

I want to set a cookie "visited=yes" if the button `bcy1` is pressed AND to change the `bcy1` button for `bcy2` button relatively. And this works! But, I can't make the button changed(to `bcy2`) if the user got checked by script if he has the "visited=yes" cookie or not.

My JS code:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
    // They've been here before.
    alert("Checking cookie... It's ON!'");
    enblc();
} else {
    alert("Checking cookie... It's Off!'");
}

function enblc() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
        // Don't do anything.
    } else {
        document.cookie = 'visited=yes; path=/';
    }
    document.getElementById('div0').innerHTML = '<input id="bcy2" type="button" onclick="dsblc()" value="Disable cookie"/>';
    document.getElementById('bcy2').focus();
}

function dsblc() {
    document.getElementById('div0').innerHTML = '<input id="bcy1" type="button" onclick="enblc()" value="Enable cookie"/>';
    document.getElementById('bcy1').focus();
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<div id="div0">
<input id="bcy1" type="button" onclick="enblc()" value="Enable cookie"/>
</div>
```

I'm getting the proper message if the cookie is on:
`Checking cookie... It's ON!` but yet, the `bcy1` displayed instead of `bcy2`.

Comment: When posting code, please post it with proper indendation.  The code as you originally posted it is impossible to read.  I have fixed the indentation for you this time.

Comment: Thanks, friend :) I'm new here. Will do my best next time

Comment: Are you sure your script executes after the html on your page loaded, not before the div is declared? If so, move your scripts before `</body>` tag.

Comment: Yes, Nikolay! You're right! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you are executing this code upon page load before the the `div0` element has been loaded.  That means that `document.getElementById('div0')` will return `null` when you first call `enblc()` and you will fail to set the initial state.

If this is the case, there is likely an error showing in the debug console from this condition and one of the first things you should learn to do is to check the debug console for script errors when something is not working properly.

The simplest solution would be to place your code that checks the initial state in a `<script>` tag that is located AFTER the HTML for `div0`.

```
<div id="div0">
<input id="bcy1" type="button" onclick="enblc()" value="Enable cookie"/>
</div>

<script>
if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited") >= 0) {
    // They've been here before.
    alert("Checking cookie... It's ON!'");
    enblc();
} else {
    alert("Checking cookie... It's Off!'");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think it is so important. It works! I feel amazing right now :)